# mysql order by field and using current date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table

```
Id   ordertype   orderdate 
1    open         09/01/2014        
2    pending      09/01/2014        
3    open         09/30/2014        
4    closed       06/01/2014        
5    closed       9/15/20143
```

I have created a mysql query to order by field which I want.

```
select * from table order by FIELD(ordertype, 'pending', 'open', 'closed'), orderdate
```

which will sort the above table by

```
Id   ordertype   orderdate    
2    pending      09/01/2014 
3    open         09/30/2014 
1    open         09/01/2014         
5    closed       09/01/2014     
4    closed       06/01/2014
```

pending first, open second, and closed at bottom.

BUT what I would like to do is that put the closed on top based on today's date.  Meaning ID # 5 will be on top until 09/01/2014 then then it will drop to the bottom with the other closed orders.

```
Id   ordertype   orderdate    
5    closed       09/01/2014 
2    pending      09/01/2014 
3    open         09/30/2014 
1    open         09/01/2014         
4    closed       06/01/2014
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select * from table order by FIELD(ordertype, 'pending', 'open', 'closed'), orderdate, orderdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case expression for this, e.g.

```
select * 
from table1 
order by
      case when ordertype = 'closed' and orderdate > curdate() then 0 else 1 end
    , FIELD(ordertype, 'pending', 'open', 'closed')
    , orderdate
```

*nb: wasn't sure if you need >curdate() or >=curdate()*

Comment: don't forget to tick this as the accepted answer please